# How to stop scrolling output in git bash (MINGW64) on windows?

Tags: bash, git-bash, mingw64

I am compiling using g++ and the output scrolls many pages.
On Unix/Linux I was able to achieve it using pipeline and "more".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### On Unix/Linux I was able to achieve it using `| more`.

Unfortunately git bash does not come with `more` installed by default.

However, less is more.
<sup>(pun intended)</sup>

You can choose to install `more` or use `| less` instead (which is included in git bash):

> **less**
>
> Page through text one screenful at a time, Search through output, Edit the command line. less provides more emulation plus extensive enhancements such as allowing backward paging through a file as well as forward movement.

Source [less Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/less.html)

You can also use an alias to define `more`:

> ```
> alias more="less -de"
> ```
>
> Adding `-d` for `--dumb` and `-e` for `--quit-at-eof` makes this alias
> closed to what more does by default.
>
> Put this alias in `%USERPROFILE%/.bashrc`

Source [Why can't I use “more” command in Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63771420/3536342), answer by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)